# Creating environtment for equation colored box

Tags: math-mode, colorbox

I was looking on the internet how to put equation in a colored box and found this:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[overload2]{empheq}

\newcommand*\mybox[1]{%
  \colorbox{gray!10}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}%
}
\empheqset{box=\mybox}
```

However, this puts every single equation in the document in a colored box and I don't want that. How can I modify this to put only certain equations in a colored box? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't pass the `overload2` option and use `empheq` where you want the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{empheq}

\newcommand*\mybox[1]{%
  \colorbox{gray!20}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}%
}
\empheqset{box=\mybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a=b
\end{equation}

\begin{empheq}{equation}
a=b
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]